# May the fours be with you!

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

[image: ![enter image description here]

In the picture above, all the numbers 1-12 are given, using only three nines. Now, I want to make a similar watch, but using fours instead of nines.

Can you make a list of the numbers 1-12 using **exactly** three fours (for each number). So, for instance, you can't do 4+4 to get 8.

A few rules:

- Combining two 4s to make 44 is not legal
- Repeating / recurring decimal representation is not legal (as used to get seven in the example watch).
- Flooring / rounding is not legal
- The answer must be exact.
- Parentheses are of course OK

You are free to use other functions, but it's possible to do this using only [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_functions) and the factorial [`!`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) (no other "Special functions" (as they are called in the wiki-article)).

Comment: May I suggest a name change one the question?
'May the fours be with you' seems fitting.

Comment: @Winther it appears to me that the factorial symbol in the picture actually is outside of the square root sign: $\sqrt{9}!$ vs $\sqrt{9!}$.  Of course the difference is extremely difficult to see, and this ambiguity could have been avoided by a simple use of parentheses.

Comment: @mathmandan: Anachor changed the image :-)

Comment: Oh, I see. I neglected to check the edit history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only 5 ops, $+,\ -,\ \times,\ \div,\ \sqrt{}$, I can get all (although it might be debatable whether the radix point counts as one)

- $1=\sqrt4 -{ 4 \over 4}$
- $2={4+4 \over 4} $
- $3=4 - { 4 \over 4}$
- $4=4+4-4$
- $5=4+{4 \over 4}$
- $6=4 + 4 -\sqrt4 $
- $7={\sqrt4 \over .4}+\sqrt4={4!+4 \over 4}$   [Solution without `!`, thanks to Somo145]
- $8=4 + \sqrt4 +\sqrt4$
- $9=(4-.4)/.4$
- $10=4 + 4 +\sqrt4$
- $11=(4+.4)/.4={4! - \sqrt4 \over \sqrt 4}$
- $12=4 + 4 +4$

In fact, you can get rid of $-$ and $\times$ and do it with three $\big(+,\div,\sqrt{} \big)$:

- $1={\sqrt4 + \sqrt4 \over 4}$
- $2={4+4 \over 4} $
- $3=\sqrt4 + { 4 \over 4}$
- $4={4+4 \over \sqrt4}$
- $5=4+{4 \over 4}$
- $6=\sqrt4 + \sqrt4 +\sqrt4 $
- $7={\sqrt4 \over .4}+\sqrt4 $  [Somo145]
- $8=4 + \sqrt4 +\sqrt4$
- $9={\sqrt4 \over .4}+4 $
- $10=4 + 4 +\sqrt4$
- $11=(4+.4)/.4$
- $12=4 + 4 +4$

Comment: @Anachor Getting rid of factorials? $\frac{\sqrt{4}}{.4} + \sqrt{4} = 7$

Comment: @Somo145 Nice one, don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: Well done! =) My answer for the tricky number 9: `cot(acos(sqrt(4)/4))^-4 = 9`. Not exactly pretty, but the radix point is avoided, and only elementary functions are used.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Impressive! Can you get rid of the radix point for 7 and 11 as well?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Nice one without the radix, I don't think I would have thought of that.