# Make expressions equal to 100 using exactly seven 4s

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Use exactly seven 4s in every expression and no other digits/numbers.

- Choose from among addition, subtraction, division, and/or multiplication operations.
- You may use parentheses, brackets, and/or braces for grouping and/or multiplication, as needed.
- This is in base ten.  (The numbers using the fours and 100 on the other side of the equals sign are in base 10.)
- You may not use decimal points.
- No concatenation is allowed.
- You may not use factorial signs.
- You may not use square roots.
- You may not use exponentiation.
- No other characters or operations may be used.

Note: Expressions with forms of A + B and B + A will be considered the same, 
as will be -A + B with B - A, and A(B) with B(A), and 
A(B) + C with C + A(B), etc.

Create a minimum of *six* essentially different solutions based on the note
above.

Comment: Somewhat related I guess. [May the fours be with you](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/22839/31824).

Comment: Given that concatenation is forbidden, how can "the numbers using the fours" even have a base?

Comment: Since you want a minimum of xx different solutions, why the restriction that concatenation is not allowed? Just accept `44+44+4+4+4` and demand at least 7 different solutions.

Comment: @ Mr. Lister - With concatenation of digits, it 1) makes this puzzle less challenging, and 2) I am trying to keep the total number of different solutions down because including concatenation would add at least three more solutions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My suggestion:

> $100=4\cdot(4\cdot4+4+4+4\div4)$
> $100=4\cdot(4+4\div4)\cdot(4+4\div4)$
> $100=4\cdot(4\cdot(4+4\div4)+4)+4$
> $100=4\cdot(4\cdot(4+4)-4-4)+4$
> $100= 4\cdot(4+4)\cdot(4-4\div4)+4$
> $100=4\cdot4\cdot4+4\cdot(4+4)+4$

Comment: That was so fast after I posted!

Answer (score 7):

Different to @ThomasL's solution, I found:

> $(4\times4)(4+\frac{4+4}{4})+4$

Comment: @ JMP - That was pretty fast after I posted the puzzle.

Comment: There just aren't that many options :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a newer one of my own:

> (4*4 + 4)(4*4 + 4)/4 = 100

Answer (score 5):

Additionally:

> (4*4 + 4)*4 + 4*4 + 4
>  = 20 * 4 + 16 + 4

Comment: @ SOLO - I looked at this about two hours after you posted it.  Thank you for it.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase

> This is in base ten. (The numbers using the fours and 100 on the other side of the equals sign are in base 10.)

makes me think using 44 is allowed. If that's the case then:

> 44 + 44 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 100

Comment: But concatenation is explicitly disallowed.

Comment: I thought that concatenation is explicitly disallowed as its own operator. (like using it on the result of another expression) example: `((4 + 4) ^ 4) + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4` where `^` denotes concatenation.

Comment: @RossMillikan if "no concatenation is allowed" means that you can't use 44, then there's no reason to say "The numbers using the fours...are in base 10.".  The digit `4` has the same value in all bases except for those bases that do not include the digit `4`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

> $((\frac{4}{4} + 4)\times 4 \times (\frac{4}{4} + 4) =100   )$

Comment: This is the same (up to reordering of the multiplication) as the second line in ThomasL's accepted solution.